# Which windows SDK includes the headers for IE IDOMCustomEvent

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, sdk, custom-event

I have installed Windows SDK 7.1 on Windows 7 to get the IDOMCustomEvent interface which is supposed to be present in mshtml.h on "Windows Vista with SP1, Windows 7".
I have grepped the entire SDK include directory and it isn't there(but mshtml.h is).  How do I get this interface?
My requirement is to fire CustomEvents into IE11 from C++.  Any way to achieve this would be acceptable.

Comment: I have found this interface in the Windows SDK 8.1 but it should, according to Microsoft, be present in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with IE9, the declaration of [IDOMCustomEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975986(v=vs.85).aspx) appears in MSHTML.IDL.

```
interface IDOMCustomEvent : IDispatch
{
  [propget, id(DISPID_IDOMCUSTOMEVENT_DETAIL)] HRESULT detail([retval, out] VARIANT * p);
  [id(DISPID_IDOMCUSTOMEVENT_INITCUSTOMEVENT)] HRESULT initCustomEvent([in] BSTR eventType,[in] VARIANT_BOOL canBubble,[in] VARIANT_BOOL cancelable,[in] VARIANT* detail);
};
```

If memory serves, this interface is responsible for supporting DOM custom events, as defined by the [DOM L3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#extending-events-Custom_Events) specification (first supported in IE9 Standards mode).  The spec shows how a custom event might be made using JavaScript.

I'm not sure how useful this is for your needs.  There is an [older article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250489(v=vs.85).aspx#basics)  that discusses a C++ implementation, but it's based on an older version of the browser and may not be relevant, especially given the changes to the security model over the years.  (I also found a [slightly more recent article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149258/Inject-HTML-and-JavaScript-into-an-existing-page-w) on CodeProject, but I haven't tried it out.)

Not sure if this helps, but perhaps the background info will help.

Comment: I eventually gave up on this line of attack because the very old code base I am working on really didn't like SDK8.1 It does seem very odd that the interface is in the IDL files and not in the headers.  In the end I used the onmessage event because this was otherwise unused and carries an arbitrary string payload.  I will flag your answer as the solution since it does shed light on the problem.